# Update form in meteor using autoform

Tags: mongodb, meteor, meteor-autoform

I have a collection that handles default values for forms. I need to build a UI to update the default values themselves, instead of force updating via mongo backed.

I've used aldeed's update-each functionality. The data is being fetched from the DB and displayed in the table. However, when I try to update by inputting new values in the textbox, it does not persist. In fact, it keeps throwing this error which i'm not aware of.

```
Exception in template helper: TypeError: Cannot read property 'namedContext' of undefined
    at Object.autoFormFieldIsInvalid
```

As a sample, here is what I'm working with:

**Mongo Collection:**

```
meteor:PRIMARY> db.testCollection.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("577ccd87f57f43d790c3ec49"), "schemaName" : "test_schema", "label" : "test_lable", "value" : "test_value" }
```

**Schema:**

```
test_schema = new SimpleSchema({
    "schemaName": {
        type: String,
    },
    "label": {
        type: String,
    },
    "value": {
        type: String,
    }
});

testCollection.attachSchema(test_schema);
```

**Template:**

```
<template name = "testTemplate">

<table class="table table-bordered table-condensed">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td style="width: 85px">Schema Name</td>
        <td style="width: 85px">Label</td>
      <td>Default Value</td>
      <td style="width: 250px">New Default Value</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    {{#each items}}
      <tr>
        <td>{{this.schemaName}}</td>
        <td>{{this.label}}</td>
        <td>{{this.value}}</td>
        <td>
        {{#autoForm id=updateDefaiultsID type="update" collection=testCollection doc=this autosave=true}}
          {{> afFormGroup name="value" label=false}}
        {{/autoForm}}
        </td>
      </tr>
    {{/each}}
  </tbody>
</table>


</template>
```

**Helper**

```
import { Template } from 'meteor/templating';
import '../templates/testTemplate.html';


if (Meteor.isServer) {

  Meteor.publish(null, function () {
    return testCollection.find();
  });

  testCollection.allow({
    update: function () {
      return true;
    }
  });
}

else if (Meteor.isClient) {

  Template["testTemplate"].helpers({
    items: function () {
      return testCollection.find({}, {sort: {name: 1}});
    },
    updateDefaiultsID: function () {
      return "testTemplate" + this._id;
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this 
from

```
<td>{{this.schemaName}}</td>
```

to

```
<td>{{this.schema_name}}</td>
```

Comment: Thanks John, however, I fail to understand how that will help. schemaName is the label defined at the mongodb level as well as the schema level.  My take is that it will actually not populate anything under the schema name column if I were to do the change you mentioned.Would you please shed some more light on this aspect?

Comment: you have to follow some data structure standards in the json format returning .......... @blueren